# How can I mark a single file as unresolved after a failed merge in git?

Tags: git, merge, conflict

at the moment I'm merging a very large project and unfortunately I have lots of conflicts. After merging some files I realized that I made merge errors in a specific file and now it is marked as resolved. How can I unresolve it in git in order to merge it again.

I tried `git reset --hard -- myFile.txt` but it doesn't work.

Regards,
  Steffen